# Deploying code on multiple server with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, devops

I'm new to Jenkins, and I like to know if it is possible to have one Jenkins server to deploy / update code on multiple web servers.

Currently, I have two web servers, which are using python Fabric for deployment.

Any good tutorials, will be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to declare your web servers as slave nodes.

- First thing, give jenkins credentials to your servers (login/password or ssh login+private key or certificate. This can be configured in the "**Manage credentials**" menu
- Then configure the slave nodes. Read the [doc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)

Then, create a multi-configuration job. First you have to install the **matrix-project** [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin). This will allow you to send the same deployment intructions to both your servers at once

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Fabic for deployment, I would suggest installing Fabric on the Jenkins master and have Jenkins kick off the Fabric commands to deploy to the remote servers.  You could set up the hostnames or IPs of the remote servers as parameters to the build and just have shell commands that iterate over them and run the Fabric commands.  You can take this a step further and have the same job deploy to dev/test/prod just by using a different set of hosts.

I would not make the webservers slave nodes.  Reserve slave nodes for build jobs.  For example, if you need to build a windows application, you will need a windows Jenkins slave.  IF you have a problem with installing Fabric on your Jenkins master, you could create a slave node that is responsible for running Fabric deploys and force anything that runs a fabric command to use that slave.  I feel like this is overly complex but if you have a ton of builds on your master, you might want to go this route.